# How do I make a node.tpl.php file that is only used by the front page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created a page--front.tpl.php successfully.

Is there a similar way to create an instance of node.tpl.php that only gets called by the front page?

That would leave the main node.tpl.php untouched to be used in the rest of the site and content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the below. This uses the [template_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6) function, and this code belongs in your active theme's template.php file:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node ( &$vars ) {
    if ($vars["is_front"]) {
        $vars["theme_hook_suggestions"][] = "node__front";
    }
}
```

and then create your template file named node--front.tpl.php, empty your site cache, and now you should have a template file for nodes specifically displayed on the front page, while your original node.tpl.php will be used everywhere else.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed!  I hope this is also helpful to other people.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://drupal.org/node/160003) is the easiest way I've found to do what you're looking for, but it seems that the best way would be to create a different "view mode" of the node (other than teaser or full) and use views or some custom php to build your front page feed using a node-my_view_mode.tpl.php